# how to set multiple names for same property

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a slight issue with behavior in python2.7 while trying to have multiple names for single property.

```
# test class

class Something():
    def __init__( self ):
        self._data_pack = 1.0

    @property
    def data_pack( self ):
        return self._data_pack
    @data_pack.setter
    def data_pack( self, value ):
        self._data_pack = value

    dataPack = data_pack


x = Something()

print( 'data_pack', x.data_pack  ) #>>> 1.0
print( 'dataPack', x.dataPack  ) #>>> 1.0
```

## in Python 3+

both return correct value of 20

```
x = Something()

#change value
x.data_pack = 20

# # both read correct value
print( 'data_pack', x.data_pack  ) #>>> 20
print( 'dataPack', x.dataPack  ) #>>> 20
```

## in Python 2

only data_pack  returns new value,
dataPack is broken

```
x = Something()

#change value
x.data_pack = 20

# # only data_pack has correct value, dataPack is broken
print( 'data_pack', x.data_pack  ) #>>> 20
print( 'dataPack', x.dataPack  ) #>>> 1.0
```

Can someone please provide some way to make sure that the OLD python behaves the same way?
With minimal changes to the source class and without 'magic' (3rd party) modules.

EDIT:
adding class derivation helped
thanks for your replies

```
class Something(object):
    def __init__( self ):
        self._data_pack = 1.0

    @property
    def data_pack( self ):
        return self._data_pack
    @data_pack.setter
    def data_pack( self, value ):
        self._data_pack = value
    dataPack = data_pack
```

Comment: Derive Something from `object` in Python 2?

Comment: by that he means try `class Something(object):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding class derivation helped solve the issue
thanks ( @AKX and @Aron_Atilla_Hegedus)

**class Something:** >>>> **class Something(object):**

```
class Something(object):
    def __init__( self ):
        self._data_pack = 1.0

    @property
    def data_pack( self ):
        return self._data_pack
    @data_pack.setter
    def data_pack( self, value ):
        self._data_pack = value
    dataPack = data_pack
```